# GORM updating null field when calling Updates()?

Tags: go, go-gorm

According to [GORM's docs](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html):

> Updates supports update with struct or map[string]interface{}, when
> updating with struct it will only update non-zero fields by default

I have an entry in my database already for the `Service` with ID, `abc123`. I am attempting to take an object that looks like the one below:

```
Service{
  ID: "abc123",
  Name: "new service name",
  CreatedAt: nil,
}
```

And use it to update the my existing record. But when I call:

```
tx.Model(&service).Updates(service)
```

the `CreatedAt` value in the database is overwritten with `nil`.  How can I update my database record without overwritting the `CreatedAt` value?

**Update:** Below is my `Service` struct

```
type Service struct {
  ID        string  `gorm:"not null;type:char(32);primary_key;column:id"`
  Name      string  `json:"name" gorm:"size:50;not null;"`
  CreatedAt *time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt *time.Time `gorm:"index"`
}
```

I've tried two different variations for my `Service` struct.  the other is with `CreatedAt` being of type `time.Time` instead of `*time.Time`.  With `*time.Time` it will overwrite the value in my DB with a null value.  With `time.Time` it attempts to overwrite the value in the DB with an uninitialized time value and throws the error: `Error 1292: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00' for column 'created_at' at row 1`

Comment: Please, provide your definition of `type Service struct {...}`

Comment: @bambula - updated

Comment: A zero value for a `time.Time` field is `time.Time{}`. Did you try that instead of `nil`?

Comment: If `CreatedAt` is `time.Time` then `CreatedAt: nil,` will not compile, can you show the acutal code, it may be of importance.

Comment: @mkopriva - you're right, I updated my struct to reflect how I actually have it setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A zero value, or a default value, for a `time.Time` field type inside a struct is `time.Time{}`. When using `Updates`, either don't populate the `CreatedAt` field, or assign `time.Time{}` value to it.

In the example below, the default or zero value is printed out for `CreatedAt` field in both cases.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type T struct {
   CreatedAt time.Time
   C int
   S string
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(T{C: 1, S: "one"})
    fmt.Println(T{C: 2, S: "two", CreatedAt: time.Time{}})
}

// {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 1 one}
// {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 2 two}
```

**EDIT:**
Also, I'm not sure how even `CreatedAt: nil,` compiles if the `CreatedAt` field is of `time.Time` type, and not `*time.Time`.

Since you've updated the `Service` struct and `CreatedAt` field type to `*time.Time`, following should work:

```
tx.Model(&service).Updates(Service{Name: service.Name}) // add all fields that you want to be updated.

// resulting query
// UPDATE services SET name = 'new service name' WHERE id = 'abc123';
```

An official GORM example is [here](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Updates-multiple-columns)

Additionally, you can omit the `created_at` field like this:

```
tx.Model(&service).Omit("created_at").Updates(service)
```

Comment: When I attempt to do it this way GORM includes `created_at` in the update statement like so: `UPDATE services SET ... created_at = '0001-01-01 00:00:00' ... WHERE ... ` and then throws the error: `ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '0001-01-01 00:00:00' for column 'created_at' at row 1` When I try to execute it

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your updates on the `Service` struct in your question.

Answer (score 2):

By default, gorm will not update default(zero) or nil values.
If you want to have control over it use something as I described below.
You can use nullable types provided by sql package or create your own.

```
type Model struct {
    Amount *sql.NullFloat64
}

// amount will not be updated
gorm.Updates(Model{Amount: nil})

// amount will be updated as a null
gorm.Updates(Model{Amount: &sql.NullFloat64{}})

// amount will be updated as a 10.50
gorm.Updates(Model{Amount: &sql.NullFloat64{Float64: 10.50, Valid: true}})
```

Answer (score 1):

use map
https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Updates-multiple-columns

```
tx.Model(&service).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"ID": "abc123", "Name": "new service name", "CreatedAt": nil})
```

Comment: It's a bit illogical that this works while the other approach not, but that's how it is.